# A Java program to modify encoding

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

I want to compile my package, but I need to change the encoding to "utf-8 without bom". The package has hundreds java files, but I don't want to open every file and save them. So can I write a program to change all the file in the package? Or some tools to use?

Comment: What is the current encoding?

Comment: there are a bunch of ways to do it. I would start and point out what OS I'm using ...

Comment: Why do you think, you cannot write such a program to change the encoding of all your source files?

Answer (score 0):

As [this post discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768763/writing-utf-8-without-bom), a Java source file without a BOM (byte order mark) is indistinguishable from a source file in plain ASCII.  That being said, to convert your UTF-8 source files to UTF without BOM, you can simply strip off the leading BOM marker.  Here is a link to code which removes the BOM mark for UTF-8 files:

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=257

Answer (score 0):

Try iconv. The program converts files between encodings, presuming you know what encoding the files are already.